# php Connection reset by peer while debugging with Xdebug

Tags: php, nginx, xdebug, magento-1.9, ioncube

I decided to post after trying several things to no avail. Hopefully someone experienced the same and have an answer for me.

I get this error: **recv() failed (104: Connection reset by peer) while reading response header from upstream** when trying to add something to the cart on magento 1.9.1, this happens only under this circumstances:

- xdebug running
- ioncube extension is enabled

As soon as I stop xdebug everything works normally, or if disable the ioncube extension and keep xdebug running it also works.

My setup: 
Nginx + php-fpm 5.5.9
I'm using sockets: /var/run/php-fpm.sock

Is there a way to overcome this?